# Access element of dictionary in pug/jade

Tags: javascript, pug

If I have a dictionary like:

```
x = {"A" : 1, "B" : 2 }
```

And I pass this dictionary into the pug file, how can I access a specific key value without iterating through all the elements in the dictionary?

For ex. `x[A]`

The only way I can think of right now is to iterate through the elements:

```
for key, val in x
```

And then have an if conditional in there that displays `val` when `key` equals `A`.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: That would be `x.A`, same as normal JavaScript.

Comment: Yep you are right :)

Comment: If you have more complicated indices than that (not just `A` or `B`.), you can also access it like an array. You were close in your original question. Just do `x["A"]`, `x["B"]`, etc

Answer (score 1):

If you passes `x` dictionary to your `.pug` file you can simply show the key `1` of this dictionary using `${x.A}`, same as in normal `javascript`.
Be sure to add back-tick between the expression.

Comment: Okay how about if this value came from another variable ..for example `y = {"X" : "A", "Y" : "B" }` and I wanted to use the value of y["X"] and pass that as key to x, i.e. `x[y["X"] = x["A"] = 1`

Comment: You can use both `${x.A}` , `${x[y["X"]]}` as well as `${x[y.X]}` as far as I know.

Answer (score -1):

every Javascript object is an associative array which is the most general sort of array you can invent - sometimes this is called a hash or map structure or a dictionary object.
An associative array is simply a set of key value pairs.
The value is stored in association with its key and if you provide the key the array will return the value. 
This is all an associative array is and the name comes from the association between the key and the value. The key is a sort of generalized address that can be used to retrieve the stored value.
For example:

```
array={key1: 'value1',key2:'value2'};
```

creates an object called array with two keys and two values which in this case happen to be two constant strings.
Notice that the value stored can be any JavaScript object and in this example it is probably better to think of storing two string objects rather two string literals. 
The key can be either an identifier, a string or a number but more about the difference in the key type as we progress.
You can retrieve a value via it key using array notation:

```
console.log(array['key2']);
```

Which displays the string value2. If you try and access a key that doesn't exist then you get the result undefined.

As the associative array is used to as the basis of the JavaScript object there is an alternative way to access a value that makes the key look like a property. That is you can access the value using "property syntax" as in:

```
console.log(array.key2);
```

So in jade/pug if you pass the **x** it will show you the similar result like in js. In your case it would be something like that:

```
${x["A"]} or ${x.A}
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: Hi , I updated my answer. Let me know if its more understandable now

Comment: hi @RBT seems like this post is not get yet enough attention. Would you suggest me please how do i improve this ? or do I make any mistake here ?